# Do I ever need to synchronize node.js code like in Java?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have only recently started developing for node.js, so forgive me if this is a stupid question - I come from Javaland, where objects still live happily sequentially and synchronous. ;)

I have a key generator object that issues keys for database inserts using a variant of the high-low algorithm. Here's my code:

```
function KeyGenerator() {
    var nextKey;
    var upperBound;

    this.generateKey = function(table, done) {
        if (nextKey > upperBound) {
            require("../sync/key-series-request").requestKeys(function(err,nextKey,upperBound) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                this.nextKey = nextKey;
                this.upperBound = upperBound;
                done(nextKey++);
            });
        } else {
            done(nextKey++);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, when I ask it for a key, I must ensure that it never, *ever* issues the same key twice. In Java, if I wanted to enable concurrent access, I would make make this `synchronized`.

1. In node.js, is there any similar concept, or is it unnecessary? I intend to ask the generator for a bunch of keys for a bulk insert using `async.parallel`. My expectation is that since node is single-threaded, I need not worry about the same key ever being issued more than once, can someone please confirm this is correct?
2. Obtaining a new series involves an asynchronous database operation, so if I do 20 simultaneous key requests, but the series has only two keys left, won't I end up with 18 requests for a new series? What can I do to avoid that?

**UPDATE**
This is the code for `requestKeys`:

```
exports.requestKeys = function (done) {
    var db = require("../storage/db");
    db.query("select next_key, upper_bound from key_generation where type='issue'", function(err,results) {
        if (err) { done(err); } else {
            if (results.length === 0) {
            // Somehow we lost the "issue" row - this should never have happened
                done (new Error("Could not find 'issue' row in key generation table"));
            } else {
                var nextKey = results[0].next_key;
                var upperBound = results[0].upper_bound;
                db.query("update key_generation set next_key=?, upper_bound=? where type='issue'",
                    [ nextKey + KEY_SERIES_WIDTH, upperBound + KEY_SERIES_WIDTH],
                    function (err,results) {
                        if (err) { done(err); } else {
                            done(null, nextKey, upperBound);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I should probably mention that consuming a key requires db access even if a new series doesn't have to be requested, because the consumed key will have to be marked as used in the database. The code doesn't reflect this because I ran into trouble before I got around to implementing that part.

**UPDATE 3**

I think I got it using event emitting:

```
function KeyGenerator() {
    var nextKey;
    var upperBound;
    var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    var requesting = true;

    // Initialize the generator with the stored values
    db.query("select * from key_generation where type='use'", function(err, results)
        if (err) { throw err; }
            if (results.length === 0) {
                throw new Error("Could not get key generation parameters: Row is missing");
            }
            nextKey = results[0].next_key;
            upperBound = results[0].upper_bound;
            console.log("Setting requesting = false, emitting event");
            requesting = false;
            emitter.emit("KeysAvailable");
    });

    this.generateKey = function(table, done) {
        console.log("generateKey, state is:\n    nextKey: " + nextKey + "\n    upperBound:" + upperBound + "\n    requesting:" + requesting + " ");
        if (nextKey > upperBound) {
            if (!requesting) {
                requesting = true;
                console.log("Requesting new series");
                require("../sync/key-series-request").requestSeries(function(err,newNextKey,newUpperBound) {
                    if (err) { return done(err); }
                    console.log("New series available:\n    nextKey: " + newNextKey + "\n    upperBound: " + newUpperBound);
                    nextKey = newNextKey;
                    upperBound = newUpperBound;
                    requesting = false;
                    emitter.emit("KeysAvailable");
                    done(null,nextKey++);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Key request is already underway, deferring");
                var that = this;
                emitter.once("KeysAvailable", function() { console.log("Executing deferred call"); that.generateKey(table,done); });
            }
        } else {
            done(null,nextKey++);
        }
    }
}
```

I've peppered it with logging outputs, and it does do what I want it to.

Comment: Without seeing the `requestKeys()` code it is difficult to answer precisely, however the answer to (2) is most probably 'yes,' it probably would end up requesting an excessive number of new key blocks in the scenario you describe and to (1) is 'probably not' unless `requestKeys` could return (callback with) the same `nextKey` to two different invocations. Question: what are you intending to happen by the `this.nextKey = nextKey` and `this.upperBound = upperBound` lines, or more precisely, what are you intending to reference by `this` in those lines?

Comment: @barry-johnson Thanks for your help, I was trying to reference the fields of the object with `this`. I had left that out because I thought it would make the code more clear, but have added the code for the surrounding object now. From your question though I'm guessing that's not right...? :(

Comment: I have also added the `requestKeys()` function. `../storage/db` is basically just a [mysql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql) connection.

Comment: Thanks - I will read the code later as I have to run out. Maybe you will get an answer before I get back. Regarding the `this` usage - it rarely is bound to what anything useful from inside a callback. Also declaring things as vars of KeyGenerator wouldn't let you use `this.` to access them. More later.

Comment: Would it work if I replaced `this` with `that` in the callback and did `var that = this` before the call to `requestKeys`?

Comment: BTW, what database are you using? Regarding your update 2, are you writing the used keys one by one into the DB? Must your sequence be monotonic, or are gaps permitted?

Comment: I'm using mysql and writing keys to it as I use them (by incrementing a next_key value in a special row). Gaps are permissible, but I'd like to avoid wasting entire series if there's a way around it.

Comment: I am still considering your original question, but is there a reason why you wouldn't simply rely on MySQL's auto_increment capability? Possibly you are using these keys outside of other database inserts? There is obviously a reason DBMSs implement this sort of thing (including similar methods like Oracle sequences, etc). The reason being that it is non trivial to implement the farther away (logically) from the 'true record' of the sequence information.

Comment: I have an Android app that is capable of working offline and then two way syncing. To avoid key collisions I need control over the primary keys.

Comment: @barry-johnson Do you think event emitting is an avenue worth pursuing for this? I was thinking I could emit an "KeysAvailable" event when a new series is available, and register any key requests that come in while a new series is being obtained as one-time listeners to that event.

Comment: That is an intriguing idea. One of the questions I wanted to ask you was whether key order was critical or not (i.e. if you make requests A, B, & C (in that order) is it essential that `A.key < B.key < C.key` ? The one issue I see in my approach, and possibly in yours relates to volume & throughput - what is the behavior if you have queued up more than a block's worth of key requests (e.g. 50 in the example)?

Comment: That's not an issue, all I require is `A.key != B.key != C.key`. If the request queue outsizes the available key range, ideally it should serve those requests it still can, then make the others wait. I.e. if there are 5 keys left, and 10 inserts queue in, the first five will get served, and the other five have to wait until keys are available again.

Comment: @barry-johnson I've come up with a working solution that is based on emitting events. However you seem to be much more knowledgeable at this than I am, so do you think you could give it a look-over and make sure I haven't just introduced a more subtle bug?

Comment: That looks reasonable. I am updating my answer to point to a gist as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer mentions, you will potentially end up with results different from what you want. Taking things in order:

```
function KeyGenerator() {
    // at first I was thinking you wanted these as 'class' properties
    // and thus would want to proceed them with this. rather than as vars
    // but I think you want them as 'private' members variables of the
    // class instance. That's dandy, you'll just want to do things differently
    // down below
    var nextKey;
    var upperBound;

    this.generateKey = function (table, done) {
        if (nextKey > upperBound) {
            // truncated the require path below for readability.
            // more importantly, renamed parameters to function
            require("key-series-request").requestKeys(function(err,nKey,uBound) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                // note that thanks to the miracle of closures, you have access to
                // the nextKey and upperBound variables from the enclosing scope
                // but I needed to rename the parameters or else they would shadow/
                // obscure the variables with the same name.
                nextKey = nKey;
                upperBound = uBound;
                done(nextKey++);
            });
        } else {
            done(nextKey++);
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the `.requestKeys` function, you will need to somehow introduce some kind of synchronization. This isn't actually terrible in one way because with only one thread of execution, you don't need to sweat the challenge of setting your semaphore in a single operation, but it is challenging to deal with the multiple callers because you will want other callers to effectively (but not really) block waiting for the first call to `requestKeys()` which is going to the DB to return.

I need to think about this part a bit more. I had a basic solution in mind which involved setting a simple semaphore and queuing the callbacks, but when I was typing it up I realized I was actually introducing a more subtle potential synchronization bug when processing the queued callbacks.

UPDATE:

I was just finishing up one approach as you were writing about your EventEmitter approach, which seems reasonable. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/barry-johnson/9874154) which illustrates the approach. I took. Just run it and you'll see the behavior. It has some console logging to see which calls are getting deferred for a new key block or which can be handled immediately. The primary moving part of the solution is (note that the `keyManager` provides the stubbed out implementation of your `require('key-series-request')`:

```
function KeyGenerator(km) {
    this.nextKey = undefined;
    this.upperBound = undefined;
    this.imWorkingOnIt = false;
    this.queuedCallbacks = [];
    this.keyManager = km;


    this.generateKey = function(table, done) {
        if (this.imWorkingOnIt){
            this.queuedCallbacks.push(done);
            console.log('KG deferred call. Pending CBs: '+this.queuedCallbacks.length);
            return;
        };
        var self=this;
        if ((typeof(this.nextKey) ==='undefined') || (this.nextKey > this.upperBound) ){
            //  set a semaphore & add the callback to the queued callback list
            this.imWorkingOnIt = true;
            this.queuedCallbacks.push(done);
            this.keyManager.requestKeys(function(err,nKey,uBound) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                self.nextKey = nKey;
                self.upperBound = uBound;
                var theCallbackList = self.queuedCallbacks;
                self.queuedCallbacks = [];
                self.imWorkingOnIt = false;
                theCallbackList.forEach(function(f){
                    // rather than making the final callback directly,
                    // call KeyGenerator.generateKey() with the original
                    // callback
                    setImmediate(function(){self.generateKey(table,f);});

                });

            });
        } else {
            console.log('KG immediate call',self.nextKey);
            var z= self.nextKey++;
            setImmediate(function(){done(z);});
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Very neat! I think our two approaches are very similar, by and large. A couple of quick questions though: 1. Is the defensive check for `nextKey === undefined` there to defer key requests before the generator has been initialized? 2. Why the use of `setImmediate` when you execute the deferred callbacks? Is it to keep the IO from freezing when a large number of key requests have queued up? 3. What's the purpose of the `QueryService`? Is that just there to mock out the database and simulate the delays it would ordinarily cause?

Comment: @chris - Sorry for delay - took a phone call that ran a bit long. You correctly surmised the reasons for each of the items. I think there is a cleaner/better way to deal with the initialization issue, but the additional conditional was the quick solution. As for the QueryService, yes, I just wanted a convenient and reliable way to simulate different possible DB latency as well as just make it capable of running fully standalone. I always hate getting example code that is dependent on a bunch of other things.

Comment: @chris - Looking at my code again, I think it would be OK to remove the `setImmediate` from the else side. In standalone testing, you can remove them in both places, but I would worry that in production that there could be excessive blocking if you had a lot of keyRequests in relation to the responsiveness of the database (although this could be addressed by getting larger key blocks), but maybe I am being overly defensive on that risk.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think without you I would still be banging my head against the keyboard in frustration over this (which never seems to help). I wish I could give you more than the meager +25 because I think the amount of work you invested into this deserves much better (especially on a Sunday...). I'll look at some of your other answers from your profile to see if I don't happen to like some of those as well. ;)

Comment: @chris Thanks for the very kind words, am very glad I could help. It was an interesting mental puzzle (and other people's problems always seem more interesting than our own for some reason LOL). Also, being more of a java guy by background myself, I am very sympathetic to the mental challenge of moving from Java to Javascript. I've actually come to really appreciate Javascript. I am hoping Oracle's project Avatar (a part of which is basically a Node server with bindings to the new JDK8 Nashorn JS engine) continues to get fleshed out, because it could be a great way to combine the two easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your Node.js code to calculate the next key didn't need to execute an async operation then you wouldn't run into synchronization issues because there is only one JavaScript thread executing code. Access to the nextKey/upperBound variables will be done in sequence by only one thread (i.e. request 1 will access first, then request 2, then request 3 et cetera.) In the Java-world you will always need synchronization because multiple threads will be executing even if you didn't make a DB call.

However, in your Node.js code *since you are making an async call to get the nextKey you could get strange results*. There is still only one JavaScript thread executing your code, but it would be possible for request 1 to make the call to the DB, then Node.js might accept request 2 (while request 1 is getting data from the DB) and this second request will also make a request to the DB to get keys. Let's say that request 2 gets data from the DB quicker than request 1 and update nextKey/upperBound variables with values 100/150. Once request 1 gets its data (say values 50/100) then it will update nextKey/upperBound. This scenario wouldn't result in duplicate keys, but you might see gaps in your keys (for example, not all keys 100 to 150 will be used because request 1 eventually reset the values to 50/100)

This makes me think that *you will need a way to sync access*, but I am not exactly sure what will be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: But if I query the database synchronously and for some reason it takes really long, won't it freeze the entire server, for all connections?

Comment: Ah sorry I see what you mean now. I was somehow misreading that last part as querying the database synchronously